# javascript Array from the request

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, jstl

`enter code here`I have a variable from the server that defines a Javascript ArrayList representing countries as follows:

```
[Belgium,Denmark,Germany,Italy,Portugal,Ireland,India,Morocco,Republic Of Korea];
```

getting the variable from the request in the jsp without quotes:

```
var countries = ${countryList};
```

I get this error:

```
SCRIPT1007: Expected ']'
```

I get no errror using quotes

```
var countries = '${countryList}';
```

but the result is not the expected. I would like to access

```
'Belgium' as countries[0] 
'Denmark' as countries[1]
```

instead of `'B' as countries[0]`, `'e' countries[1]` , etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing server-side and client-side. You need to iterate over your list with JSTL, so that you can build your JavaScript array:

```
var countries = [];
<c:forEach items="${countryList}" var="country"> 
    countries.push('${country}');
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Why rebuild the array in javascript? Why not build it on the server and pass it to javascript?